# How to run golang tests after automatic compile from dev_appserver

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am running dev_appserver.py and so it auto builds as I save go files (I need to run this and not goapp because of log_level I need).

When there is a successful build I would like the tests for the project (goapp test) to run automatically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like https://github.com/nf/watch in a separate terminal window. It'll re-run tests in parallel to `dev_appserver.py`.

Install: `go get github.com/nf/watch`

Run from your app's directory: `watch goapp test`

Comment: I ended up setting a grunt task (since I am using grunt watch to monitor client side for testing). I think I will take this code and have the go tests run after the build.

Answer (score 0):

With AppEngine, I use the [`entr`](http://entrproject.org/) app like so:

```
$ find ./*.go | entr goapp test
```